# Buy used 10 year old Blues Jr. for 400€

Tags: guitar, amplifiers

I am going to check out a used Fender blues junior, limited edition bought in 2010. The owner wants to sell it for 400 euros.

I dont think the tubes have ever been changed though the owner insisted that the amp has not been used a lot. Do I need to change the tubes for such an amp?

What are your opinions on this? Is it actually a good deal?

Any other tips for buying used tube amps?

Here are some pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The aspect about maintenance is on topic.  The "is this a good deal" is off topic.

Comment: You should assume that the tubes will need maintenance, if not now, then eventually.  Do your research and find out what it costs to do the maintenance, and if you wouldn't be able to do it, then don't buy the amp.

Answer (score 2):

We don't do "shopping advice" I'm afraid.
**"Is it worth it?"** is something only the purchaser can decide.

Your worry about valves is an easy fix… buy new valves.

Tips for buying used valve amps - put new valves in & see if it's better.
If it isn't, then next is change the capacitors.

A discrete component amp is **always** fixable at component-level.
Whether you can DIY or have to pay a pro will be the main influence on your decision as to **"Is it worth it?"**

Answer (score 0):

2010 means it's a fairly new amp. If it hasn't been used much the tubes will probably be ok. In any case it's usually only the power tubes that might need replacement, they wear out from use. Pre-amp tubes last basically forever if they are manufactured right.

If I were to buy such an amp I would plug it in with one of my guitars and check the function of all knobs and switches. If everything checks out functionally you need to decide subjectively if it sounds and feels good to you.